# Use of the future tense after the phrase "I'll let you know when..."

Tags: future-tense, let

Which sentence should I use?

> I'll let you know when **I** have more information.

> I'll let you know when **I'll** have more information.

Also, what is the proper grammatical explanation for the correct version?

Comment: "I will let you know when I have more information." is correct. You don't use the future tense in an adverbial clause.

Comment: I think this question has been already asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both can be correct, but I would expect that the first version is the one that you would actually want most of the time.

In the first version, "I'll let you know when I have more information", there are two time points.  At time T (now) you don't have more information.  You are promising that at some time T+1, you will have more information, and at that same time T+1 you will inform them of this information.

In the second version, "I'll let you know when I will have more information", there are three time points.  At time T (now) you don't have more information.  At some time (T+1) you will have a schedule.  This schedule gives a time (T+2) at which you will have more information.  You are promising that at time (T+1), when you have the schedule, you will inform them of the schedule.